# django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Oracle 19 or later is required (found 12.2.0.1.0)

Tags: python, django, oracle, oracle12c, instantclient

Note: I installed oracle instance for windows

```
with connections['trdb'].cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    col = cursor.description
    cursor.close
```

Comment: The error seems pretty clear - you need v19 or newer, but only have v12 installed.

Comment: the same problem when setup win 11